# WKWebView InAppBrowser Persistent Storage

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, wkwebview, inappbrowser

Does Apache Cordova's (and subsequently Ionic's) InAppBrowser plugin allow for persistent storage (localStorage, indexedDB, etc.) when using the WKWebView version?

If it does, and someone were to tell you that it does not because it is WKWebView, what would you suggest showing them to prove it does?